# Caption appearance

Tags: captions

Everytime I write a caption of a figure or table that occupies more than one line it appears in the document like

```
Figure 6.2: Polarization curves at 750C for 3P_{CO}=P_{H_{2}} at the
            initial water concentrations of 3.2, 6.4, 9.6, 15, 20 and 25%.
```

And I want it to appear like

```
Figure 6.2: Polarization curves at 750C for 3P_{CO}=P_{H_{2}} at the
initial water concentrations of 3.2, 6.4, 9.6, 15, 20 and 25%.
```

What should I do?

Thanks,

Ramon

Comment: Which document class are you using?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look on [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. It is very important for us to know which `documentclass` you are using, as some of them treat `caption`s differently from others. Could you post a small, complete, [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv)

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. A suggestion: Do us a favour and change your username to something more telling than "user1234".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The bahaviour you describe is the default in KOMA classes; you can change this by setting `\setcapindent` to `0pt` to get the desired result:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\setcapindent{0pt}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
A
\caption{Test figure with some addtional text spanning more than one line just for the example and some more text}
\end{figure}

\begin{table}
\centering
B
\caption{Test table with some addtional text spanning more than one line just for the example and some more text}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]